# Map a nested DTO object to a single item list using mapstruct

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mapstruct, data-transfer-objects

I have a DTO that with a nested object that I need to convert into a list.

Here's the general idea (in Kotlin):

DTO (source):

```kotlin
class PersonDto {
    var name: NameDto,
    var otherField: String
}
```

Target:

```kotlin
class Person {
    var name: List<Name>,
    var otherField: String
}
```

Where name in target should have just one item: the converted NameDto.

I know I can do something like this:

```
fun nameDtoToNameList(nameDto: NameDto) : List<Name> {
     // a bunch of manual code to do the conversion
}
```

but I would love to know if it's possible to do the conversion automatically.

Ideally there would be a solution that could use a nameDtoToName function that would be implemented in a NameMapper interface.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for hours and haven't gotten anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify @Mapping on the field and set the mapping to `name.get(0)`.

refer this link for syntax : https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#basic-mappings